# Update NSG with JSON definition. Only permission is contributor on the NSG resource

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-rm-template, azure-cli, azure-nsg

I have a file called `nsg-properties.json` which looks like this:

```
{
    "securityRules": [
        <twenty NSG rules are here>
    ]
}
```

I have a service principal with only a single role assignment, which is `Contributor` on the scope `/subscriptions/$SUBSCRIPTION_ID/resourceGroups/$VNET_RESOURCE_GROUP/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/$NSG_NAME` which is the resource ID of my NSG.

How can I programmatically update the NSG with the property definition in `nsg-properties.json`? Things I've tried:

- Use ARM template. Didn't work, because my service principal doesn't have `Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/write` on the scope of my resource group.
- Use `az resource create --id $NSG_ID --properties @nsg-properties.json`. Didn't work, because my service principal doesn't have `Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/read` on the scope of my resource group.

There's the `az network nsg update` API, but I can't figure out how to use a JSON definition as input.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot work like this. *You need to give `Network Contributor` OR `Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/write` permission to your Service principle in order to update NSG.*  Check out [Permissions required to make changes to NSG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/manage-network-security-group#permissions):

[image]

#### Edit:

---

In the 2nd case you have mentioned:

> Use az resource create --id $NSG_ID --properties @nsg-properties.json.
> Didn't work, because my service principal doesn't have
> Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/read on the scope of
> my resource group.

This is not possible without giving `Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/read` role to your SP. This is how the design is.

Comment: My SP has the `Contributor` on the NSGs, which does give the `Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/write` permission on the scope `/subscriptions/$SUBSCRIPTION_ID/resourceGroups/$VNET_RESOURCE_GROUP/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/$NSG_NAME` . The wall I'm hitting, is that my SP for some reason also needs `Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/read` on the RG scope

Comment: If you are creating a resource in RG using `az resource create`, you have to give Contributor role to your SP on RG as well.

Comment: This is not quite true... I discovered yesterday that Reader role is sufficient on the RG. I would consider writing this as an answer, but it doesn't address my question.

Comment: Can you share the link which says this?

Comment: There's no link, just my own experiments. It makes sense, though, as my error said I lack `Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/read` on the RG scope, and the `Reader` role does indeed grant that permission.

Comment: Got it. This is because you have given Contributor role for NSG (which has read and write as well) and now only reading RG role is required. Let me grab some links.